# Display query-set results on a Django template without using a django model

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, django-2.1

AttributeError at /Blog/mycustomsql

module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'META'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Blog/mycustomsql
Django Version:     2.1.5
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:

module 'django.http.request' has no attribute 'META'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\c822208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\context_processors.py in debug, line 40
Python Executable:  C:\Users\c822208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.3
Python Path:

['C:\cygwin64\home\c822208\django\hr',
 'C:\Users\c822208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
 'C:\Users\c822208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
 'C:\Users\c822208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
 'C:\Users\c822208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
 'C:\Users\c822208\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Wed, 9 Oct 2019 08:58:49 +0000

```py
def mycustomsql(self): 
    import cx_Oracle
    conn_string = cx_Oracle.connect('hr/passwd@127.0.0.1/xe')
    cursor1=conn_string.cursor()
    cursor2=conn_string.cursor()

    cursor1.execute("SELECT p.name,p.value FROM   v$parameter p  ORDER BY p.name")
    results1 = cursor1.fetchall()
    cursor2.execute("SELECT p.name,p.value FROM   v_param p  ORDER BY p.name")
    results2 = cursor2.fetchall()
    for index in range(0,len(results1)):
       if results2[index] == results1[index]:
          # print ('Found')
          continue
       rs= (results1[index],"   :   ",results2[index])
       # return HttpResponse(rs) -- this is giving me one row instead of 2
       context = {
        "object_list": rs
            }
       return render(request, "Blog/param.html", context)

 python python_tut/query.py
localhost/xe  -  ('shared_pool_size', '0') : localhost/xe  -  ('shared_pool_size', '5')
localhost/xe  -  ('streams_pool_size', '0') : localhost/xe  -  ('streams_pool_size', '8')
```

Comment: please, check your indents in question on python code. Now "return" in "for"

Comment: I figured the problem was request that was not imported